Porque la imagen no esta siendo importada en mi web?
estoy utilizando Cloud firestore y estoy intentando importar datos hacia React JS. Me importa todo, el unico error son mis imagenes las cuales no me las toma. Las estoy pasando como un tipo string ya que en otro proyecto anterior las pase asi y me funcionaron. Adjunto mi código. Intente poner una foto de firestore pero no logre subirla. El codigo de abajo es el de CARDS.JSX, continuo sin saber cual es el error ya que la consola no me toma nada, ningun error ni nada por el estilo por lo que debe ser algo pequeño lo que me esta ocasionando esto
import Cards from "../Cards/Cards"
import "../Amor/Amor.css"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { db } from "../../Services/config"
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore"


const Drama = () => {

const [dramaMovies, setDramaMovies] = useState([])

useEffect(() =>{
    
    const movies = collection(db, "peliculasDrama");
    getDocs(movies)
    .then(res=>{
        const pelisFirebase = res.docs.map(doc =>{
            const data = doc.data()
            return {id:doc.id, ...data}
        })
        console.log("Películas obtenidas:", pelisFirebase);
        setDramaMovies(pelisFirebase)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
    console.log("fracasaso")
},[]);



return (
<>
    <h2 className="h2-seccion">Películas de Drama</h2>
    <div className="drama-container">
        {dramaMovies.map((movie) => (<Cards key={movie.id} {...movie}/>))}
    </div>
</>
)
}

export default Drama

Card.JSX
   import "./Cards.css"
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

    const Cards = ({ title, poster, rating, tags, descripcion, id,}) 
   => 
    {


return (
    <Link to={`/movie/${id}`}>
        <div className="card">
                <div className="poster"><img src={poster} alt= 
{title} 
  /></div>
                <div className="details">
                    <h1>{title}</h1>
                    <h2>Valoración: {rating}/5</h2>
                    <div className="tags">
                        {tags.map((tag, index) => (
                            <span key={index} className="tag">{tag} 
</span>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                        <p className="desc">{descripcion}</p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </Link>
   )
   }

   export default Cards


Agrega Cards por favor, me parece que ahì radìca el problema
